# 'Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition' after adding react-native-router-flux Action()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I have a new React Native app - using redux, reduxThunk and react-native-router

I have a listItem component which triggers a redux action `addBrandForUser()` when the user clicks it.

```
class ListItem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onAddClick = this.onAddClick.bind(this);
    }

    onAddClick() {
        let {addBrandForUser, brand} = this.props;
        addBrandForUser({userId: null, brand: brand});
    }

    render() {
        let {brand} = this.props;

        return (
            <Text style={styles.brandSelectItem}
                  onPress={this.onAddClick}>
                {brand.title}
            </Text>
        )
    }
}
```

The click triggers the following action:

```
export const addBrandForUser = ({userId, brand}) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: types.AddBrandToUser,
            payload: {userId, brand}
        });

        dispatch({
            type: types.SelectBrand,
            payload: brand
        });

        //Actions.main();
    }
}
```

Which then gets evaluated in all the correct reducers. This all works and is linked up correctly - all the debuggers hit where I'm expecting them to.

However, I'm getting the `` Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount `` exception .... but only if the `Actions.main();` line is uncommented.

My router configuration is as follows:

```
export default class RouterComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Scene key="main" component={Main} title="Butler" hideNavBar={true} initial/>
                <Scene sceneStyle={{paddingTop: 60}} key="addBrand" component={AvailableBrands} title="Brands" hideNavBar={false}/>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

One thing I'm noticing is that after the `SelectBrand` action is dispatched, the reducers update correctly and the views are updated accordingly when navigating back to the Actions.main(). However, after dispatching the `AddBrandToUser` action, the reducer gets the correct payload and is correctly returning the new object, but the views aren't updating accordingly.

The view which should be updated is as follows

```
class UserBrandList extends Component {

    renderBrands(brand) {
        return <BrandSelectItem brand={brand}/>;
    }

    render() {
        let {flex1} = sharedStyles;
        console.log('Render() ... Props.Brands: ');
        console.log(this.props.brands);

        return (
            <ScrollView style={flex1}>
                <ListView
                    enableEmptySections={true}
                    dataSource={this.props.brands}
                    renderRow={this.renderBrands.bind(this)}
                />
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}

const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log('MapStateToProps() .... state.userBrands: ');
    console.log(state.userBrands);
    return {
        brands: ds.cloneWithRows(state.userBrands)
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserBrandList);
```

Below is some output from logging inside the above class. This sequence starts when the `addBrandForUser()` action is triggered on the listItem.

It looks like the new array is being correctly reduced, but reverts back to its former self because of the exceptions.

[image]

**Update 1:**
Here is the reducer that `addBrandForUser()` hits.

```
export default (state = [], action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case types.RefreshUserBrands:
            return action.payload;

        case types.AddBrandToUser:
            let newArray = [...state, action.payload.brand];
            console.log('New Reduced Array: ' );
            console.log(newArray);
            return newArray;

        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

**Update 2:**
`Actions` is a class provided to me by react-native-router-flux:

```
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
<Scene key="main" component={Main} title="Butler" hideNavBar={true} initial/>
```

`Actions.main()` from what I understand, routes to the `scene` with the key `main`

The component attached to the `Main` route is as follows:

```
export default class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.openSideMenu = this.openSideMenu.bind(this);
        this.closeSideMenu = this.closeSideMenu.bind(this);
    }

    closeSideMenu() {
        this._drawer.close()
    }

    openSideMenu() {
        this._drawer.open()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <ButlerHeader openDrawer={this.openSideMenu}/>

                <Drawer
                    type="overlay"
                    ref={(ref) =>  {this._drawer = ref }}
                    content={<SideMenu closeDrawer={this.closeSideMenu} />}
                    openDrawerOffset={0.2}
                    drawerpanCloseMask={0.2}
                    closedDrawerOffset={-3}
                    tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({
                            main: { opacity:(2-ratio)/2 }
                        })}
                />

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `Actions.main()` do? If that line triggers the error, it's the one you need to be digging into…

Comment: Actions.main() hits the router per my configuration in the Router Component. I'm using react-native-router-flux

Comment: Could you show your reducers?

Comment: If you comment out `Actions.main()`, does `AddBrandToUser ` update view?

Comment: Can't tell because if I don't call Actions.main() I don't route to the new scene.

Comment: Seems the problem not be solved. And I found thing interesting. Take a look. [react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/REDUX_FLUX.md#reduxflux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/REDUX_FLUX.md#reduxflux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the order doesn’t matter… and instead your `Actions.main()` is triggered first, then you’re attempting to change data while it’s trying to navigate.
that’s likely what’s happening.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you showed the code to `Action.main`. However I guess that action creator is somewhat messing with the state, or there is some async stuff going on you didn't mention.

A little hack that could work in this case is to postpone your `Actions.main` call by wrapping it in a:

`setTimeout(() => Actions.main(), 0)`

so it runs on the next tick, after dispatching and state updating has finished.

Just to be clear: this is not the way to go and this kind of bugs are normally a nice code smell that something should be done differently. ;)

Comment: 100% agreed it's most likely a code smell, and I'm definetely not trying to use any hacks to bandage it. I updated my question regarding Actions.main() under update 2 in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer is selected. I just want to post what I found.

The conclusion is that `Action.main()` will finally call `setState()` method.

And maybe `react-native-router-flux` should be used like [this way](http://react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/REDUX_FLUX.md#reduxflux).

First, `Action.main()` will call `this.callback` from [react-native-router-flux/blob/master/src/Actions.js](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/src/Actions.js) L180.

```
this[key] =
  (props = {}) => {
    assert(this.callback, 'Actions.callback is not defined!');
    this.callback({ key, type, ...filterParam(props) });
  };
```

`this.callback` is defined in [react-native-router-flux/blob/master/src/Router.js](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/src/Router.js) L137.

```
Actions.callback = (props) => {
  const constAction = (props.type && ActionMap[props.type] ? ActionMap[props.type] : null);
  if (this.props.dispatch) {
    if (constAction) {
      this.props.dispatch({ ...props, type: constAction });
    } else {
      this.props.dispatch(props);
    }
  }
  return (constAction ? onNavigate({ ...props, type: constAction }) : onNavigate(props));
};
```

And then `onNavigate` is passed by `renderNavigation(navigationState, onNavigate)` in L132. And `renderNavigation` is passed to `<NavigationRootContainer>` in L156.
`NavigationRootContainer` is imported by `NavigationExperimental`.

From [react-native-experimental-navigation/blob/master/NavigationRootContainer.js](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-experimental-navigation/blob/master/NavigationRootContainer.js), we can get `onNavigate` is exactly `handleNavigation`. In there, you can find `setState`.

```
  handleNavigation(action: Object): boolean {
    const navState = this.props.reducer(this.state.navState, action);
    if (navState === this.state.navState) {
      return false;
    }
    this.setState({
      // $FlowFixMe - navState is missing properties :(
      navState,
    });

    if (this.props.persistenceKey) {
      AsyncStorage.setItem(this.props.persistenceKey, JSON.stringify(navState));
    }

    return true;
  }
```